# Unable to access jarfile C:\..\apache-jmeter-5.5\bin\\..\lib\cmdrunner-2.2.jar

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I'm trying to create a csv from summary report using the JMeter Command Line Graph Plotting Tool plugin. I'm using this command to run test and generate report in non-gui mode.

```
JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-csv summary-report.csv --input-jtl result.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

When I run it I'm getting this error.

`Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\Users\I563673\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.5\apache-jmeter-5.5\bin\\..\lib\cmdrunner-2.2.jar`

I manually downloaded the cmdrunner-2.2.jar from [here](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=kg/apc/cmdrunner/2.2/cmdrunner-2.2.jar) and put it in the lib folder but now I'm getting the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WRJk.png)

Since the Home directory was detected as the lib folder I tried putting the jtl file in the lib directory and also specifying the path of jtl file w.r.t the lib folder. This too didn't remove the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below command to generate the result.
Go to the jmeter/bin folder if in linux machine. Else use jmeter.bat file

```
jmeter -g name-of-jtl-file -o name-of-the-output-folder
```

This will create a html and statistics.json file.
It will resolve your problem.